# Avg, partition and where SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, partition

Here is my example

[SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34cf0/6).

Could anybody explain why `AvgQuant` is invalid column name?

Also SQLfiddle is great tool, but how do I set rounding settings? For example, rounding is not correct in the following example (just remove where clause)

```
SELECT [Location]
  ,Avg([Quantity]) over (partition BY LOCATION) AS AvgQuant
  ,[Street]
FROM tblExample;
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `WHERE` clause executes before projection thus the alias isn't available in this phase. You must use subquery to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT [Location]
      ,Avg([Quantity]) over (partition BY LOCATION) AS AvgQuant
      ,[Street]
  FROM tblExample
) A
WHERE AvgQuant between 3.5 and 5.5;
```